# Weird Caching Issue EF Code First Application SQL Server 2014

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I'm working on a basic CRUD application in .Net MVC using EF code first.

I've come across an issue I've never really come across before.

Basically any changes I make to the database backend aren't being reflected in the application unless I reboot the website on the server, or re-deploy the app.

I've got another app in development and it has the exact same issue.

Any changes I make using the app are fine but any manual updates to the SQL backend aren't getting pulled through.

I'm pretty sure it isn't on the client side I've done a hard refresh, manually cleared all my browsing data and installed cache killer on my browser.

Any ideas how I can start debugging this issue?

Thanks

Here is what my db context file looks like:

```
 public partial class MyContext: DbContext
    {

        public MyContext() : base("name=MyContext")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<MyDbSet> MyDbsets { get; set; }
        etc...


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
```

I'm calling it in my MVC layer using unity:

```
 private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();

            // register all your components with the container here
            // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers

            // e.g. container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>(); 

            // repos
            ...my repos

            // service
           ... my serives


            container.RegisterType<MyContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

            RegisterTypes(container);

            return container;
        }
```

I've set up dozens of apps in this way and never had this issue.. also don't understand the down vote.. it a genuine question

Comment: How are you managing your entity sets?  Are you opening/closing/disposing of your DbContexts appropriately, or trying to use some kind of static DbContext or singleton pattern to do data access?  Do you have reproducible samples?

Comment: I've got my DbContext file in my data access layer and using unity to register it in my MVC layer like so:  container.RegisterType<MyDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

Comment: Using `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` means that the context instance returned has the same lifetime as the container (per session).  If you always use the same container instance per session you will keep reusing the same context instance, which is not recommended.  You should always create a new context instance for every "logical unit of work", and dispose of it afterwards.  contexts with long lifetimes can exhibit very strange behavior.

Comment: @BradleyUffner quite right HierarchicalLifetimeManagerwas wrong thing to use - changed to PerRequestLifetimeManager and everything is fine! Thanks for the pointer, don't know why I'd used it in the first place.

Comment: I'll add an answer based on my comment since it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` means that the `context` instance returned has the same lifetime as the container (per session). If you always use the same container instance per session you will keep reusing the same `context` instance, which is not recommended. You should always create a new `context` instance for every "logical unit of work", and dispose of it afterwards. Contexts with long lifetimes can exhibit very strange behavior (usually manifested as "caching") and poor performance.

`PerRequestLifetimeManager` will return a new instance of the `context` each time you request it, which will take care of reusing the same `context` instance over and over.